# Deserialize array of objects to c# class returns null in Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: c#, list, json-deserialization

I have this class in my App:

```
public class Control
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ControlDescription { get; set; }
    public string ControlExceptionText { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public double DataRetrieving_Frequency { get; set; }
    public double delay_Factor { get; set; }
    public Boolean Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

My json string is :

```
var result = 
"[
{\"id\":16,\"name\":\"trest\",\"controlDescription\":null,\"controlExceptionText\":null,\"color\":\"#abdb2c\",\"dataRetrieving_Frequency\":0.0,\"delay_Factor\":0.0,\"disabled\":false},
{\"id\":15,\"name\":\"test\",\"controlDescription\":null,\"controlExceptionText\":null,\"color\":\"#441fed\",\"dataRetrieving_Frequency\":1440.0,\"delay_Factor\":10.0,\"disabled\":false},
{\"id\":14,\"name\":\"Powershell\",\"controlDescription\":\"text. \",\"controlExceptionText\":\"exception.\",\"color\":\"#ad89d7\",\"dataRetrieving_Frequency\":1440.0,\"delay_Factor\":10.0,\"disabled\":false}
]"
```

and I want to deserialize this json to fit my `Control class`. So I did this to convert my Deserializeobject:

```
List<Control> test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Control>>(result);
```

the problem is that `test` returns `null`.

Any idea?!

Update:

- This code works fine in my other app, but not in `Xamarin.Form` app.
- Tried also to append `@` to the begining of the JSON string but get this error

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value @.

Update:

I'm using Xamarin Live Player to review my app, and Perhaps the problem is related to this, because many developers are complaining about serializing and deserializing bugs when using Live Player.

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Control is a class in System.Web.UI namespace. If you include that namespace in your code then you have to specify namespace before your Control class e.g. List<YourNamespace.Control>

Comment: you sure mate? https://prnt.sc/iia1m0

Comment: can you please open up exception settings (ctrl + shift + e) and see if you have any exceptions?

Comment: Namespace is included, I posted only the class for the simplicity.

Comment: If System.Web.UI namespace is included in your code then try this... List<Yournamespace.Control> test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Yournamespace.Control>>(result);

Comment: No exception, everything is fine, but null value.

Comment: With the exact same code, I'm getting the result. So the problem lies somewhere else, which you haven't provided yet. Is this a web project? Are you sure the string is formatted correctly? Can you try adding `@` to the `"[` line and Ctrl + H'ing `\"`s into `""`s? Because that's the only difference I made, your example is no valid string.

Comment: I tested the code with adding "@" before the result string, but got an error, it is a cross-platform app with xamarin-forms.

Comment: @SaadAli The literal code you posted for assigning to `result` should not compile unless you make it one line.

Comment: @SaadAli Hello, have you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: Not really, I think the problem is related to Xamarin.Form, because it is working fine in my other app. I even tried to make my string without "\" and made it valid json string, and again not working.

Comment: @SaadAli You said above: "I tested the code with adding "@" before the result string, but got an error, it is a cross-platform app with xamarin-forms." If it's the same error, can you post details and edit your question?

Comment: So @SaadAli, your problem is resolved now?

Answer (score 0):

Your json string is not correct.

> JSON data is written as name/value pairs.
>
> A name/value pair consists of a field name (in double quotes),
>   followed by a colon, followed by a value: `"name":"John"`

Remove backslashes from your json string. For the future you can check correctness of your json string [here](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: The backslashes are there to delimit the double quotes since the OP is displaying json as a literal C# string assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialization works with this string format:[image]

So to answer your question: You need a valid JSON string to make the deserialization. Start with a `@` at the top, and replace all `\"` into double quotes.

Update edit: `@` sign should be outside of the string, it's not part of the JSON string, it's just an indicator that your string will be multiline.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Here's another example I have tried so far without deserialization.
I'm getting a response as a JSON file. my JSON looks like this.

[image]

[image]

..and I did this to get each elements from the JSON. and I have fit those elements to the monkeys List.

```
using (JsonDocument document = JsonDocument.Parse(response, options))
            {
                Grid grid = new Grid();
                Monkeys = new List<Monkey>();
                foreach (JsonElement element in document.RootElement.EnumerateArray())
                {
                    if (element.TryGetProperty("id", out JsonElement id)&&(element.TryGetProperty("end", out JsonElement end) )
                        && (element.TryGetProperty("time", out JsonElement time) && (element.TryGetProperty("description", out JsonElement description)
                        && (element.TryGetProperty("start", out JsonElement start) && (element.TryGetProperty("date", out JsonElement date))))))
                    {    
                        Monkeys.Add(new Monkey
                        {
                            Time=time.ToString(),
                            Start = start.ToString(),
                            End =end.ToString(),
                            Description = description.ToString()
                        });
                        BindingContext = this;
                    }
                }
            }
```

and this is my monkey class

```
public class Monkey
    {
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Start { get; set; }
        public string End { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Start;
        }
    }
```